# Multilines aligned to describe a set notation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align

I'm trying to write a set notation in multiple lines, for example:

[image]

This is my code to get it.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
...  
\begin{align*}
Lookup &= \{\, \langle C, A.m, B.m \rangle   \mid & \textrm{class $A$ contains virtual method $m$, $C \le^{*} B \le^{*} A$}, \\
            &      & \textrm{class $B$ contains virtual method $m$}, \\
            &      & \textrm{there is no class $B^{'}$ tht contains method $m$ such that $C \le^{*} B^{'} <^{*} B$}
\, \}\\
LC &= \{\, \langle a, b \rangle \mid \langle a, b, c \rangle \in ...\, \}
\end{align*}
```

However, I can't make the second `&` aligned correctly.

[image]

What might be wrong?

### ADDED

[image]
I replaced the second `&` with `&&` to get the lines aligned correctly.
However, I see too much space between the `$\mid$` and `$class A$`. Is there a way to control the gap between them?

### ADDED2

With Barbara's help, this is my working code.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align*}
 \textit{Lookup} &= \{\, \langle C, A.m, B.m \rangle   \mid {}
   \begin{aligned}[t] &\text{class $A$ contains ...}, \\
            & \text{class $B$ contains ...}, \\
            & \text{there is no class $B'$ that contains ...} \, \}
   \end{aligned}\\
\rlap{LC}\hphantom{\textit{Lookup}}
       &= \{\, \langle a, b \rangle \mid \langle a, b, c \rangle \in ...\, \}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Use a double `&&` for the second alignment point, so that becomes `l`eft aligned instead of `r`ight aligned.

Comment: The spacing you show in your updated example is due to the second line. To eliminate that, you could enclose the right hand side of the second line within a `\rlap{$\displaystyle ... $}`.

Comment: Note that `B^{'}` is wrong; the correct way to input it is simply `B'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i suggest using the sub-environment `aligned` to handle the three conditions.  also, since the apostrophe is automatically treated as a prime (in the desired location), i'd omit the explicit superscript code -- that is what is causing the interline spacing to be irregular.

here's my suggestion:

```
\begin{align*}
 \textit{Lookup} &= \{\, \langle C, A.m, B.m \rangle   \mid {}
   \begin{aligned}[t] &\text{class $A$ contains ...}, \\
            & \text{class $B$ contains ...}, \\
            & \text{there is no class $B'$ that contains ...}
   \end{aligned}\\
\rlap{LC}\hphantom{\textit{Lookup}}
       &= \{\, \langle a, b \rangle \mid \langle a, b, c \rangle \in ...\, \}
\end{align*}
```

with the result

[image: output of code example]

it's also not necessary to use `\textrm`; just `\text` will do in most situations (unless you happen to be in a theorem, for example).  i've left-aligned the pre-equal-sign elements since that is what was in your first example -- this required the use of an artificially widened component to match the "Lookup" in the first line.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, the issue with this approach is that the closing bracket `}` is at the first line not the last line that I expected. In your code example, the enclosing `}` is missing.

Comment: @prosseek -- ah, i thought it looked like something was missing.  what i'd do is put the `\}` that completes the "lookup" condition at the end of the last line within the `aligned` block.  since it's not being sized, there are no constraints on where it can go.  (admittedly, a computer algebra system would almost certainly not accept this approach.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Peter's help, I could make it work.

This is the modified code:

```
\begin{align*}
Lookup &= \{\, \langle C, A.m, B.m \rangle   \mid && \textrm{class $A$ contains virtual method $m$, $C \le^{*} B \le^{*} A$}, \\
            & && \textrm{class $B$ contains virtual method $m$}, \\
            & && \textrm{there is no class $B^{'}$ tht contains method $m$ such that $C \le^{*} B^{'} <^{*} B$}
\, \}\\
LC &= \rlap{$\{\, \langle a, b \rangle \mid \langle a, b, c \rangle \in \textrm{there is no class $B^{'}$ tht contains method $m$ such that $C \le^{*} B^{'} <^{*} B$}\, \}$}
\end{align*}
```

This is the result:
[image]